# Multiple socket connection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets

I have 6 devices, price checkers. I have a project which the client in a supermarket will scan a product on this device and it will return the price of the product. I have managed to connect with one device, get the bar code and send data. But I can not seem to do to connect with multiple socket connection.
This is the code when I receive and send data:

Connecting with the device:

```
private void connect1(string adip, int porta)
        {
            try
            {
                IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(adip), porta);
                connect1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                connect1.Connect(ip);
            }
            catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            }
        }
```

Getting the barcode:

```
private void getbarCode()
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int receivedDataLength = lidhje.Receive(data);
            numberCodeBar = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength);
        }
```

Sending data to device:

```
private void sendData(string price1)
        {
            try
            {
                Object objData = price1;
                byte[] price = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objData.ToString());

                connect1.Send(price);
            }
            catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            }
        }
```

I want to connect with multiple decives in the same time, and when someone scans a barcode to the device the software will return to this device the price. I have searched Google, here on stackoverflow and codeproject but no luck.
Any sample code will appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just create multiple sockets and connect each of them? What's the concrete problem you are having?

Comment: Because I have to do it dynamically. The user might add or remove devices, the list of devices (IP and port) will be saved on database. When the software launches it will retrieve the list of devices and connect with them. Then the software will wait for devices to request for product price when someone scans a product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create multiple sockets in order to communicate with clients concurrently.  See associated links for sample code.

Whether or not your application will be a client or a server will depend on how the *price checker* expects to be communicated with.

To make your life easier, focus on making a *synchronous* solution work first.  You should only use *asynchronous* code when you fully understand how it works.

## Additional Reading

- [MSDN: Synchronous Client Socket Example](http://Synchronous%20Client%20Socket%20Example)
- [MSDN: Synchronous Server Socket Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MSDN: Asynchronous Client Socket Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MSDN: Asynchronous Server Socket Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Actually the devices are configured as Server. This is a screenshot
http://prntscr.com/7fbrbr 
So, I think I am the client. Am I right?

Comment: From the screenshot, it appears that the *price checker* is configured to be a server. If that is the case, then you your application will be the client... it will be expected to connect to the server.

Comment: For future reference, a good place to start looking for sample code is: http://msdn.microsoft.com.

Comment: I did. But nothing. :/ I will see the examples but which one? The Client socket right?

Comment: Before you go any further, I would ensure that your environment has been setup properly. Has the *Price Checker* been configured correctly?  Are you connecting to the right IP & port address?  The firewall on the server (and possibly the client) may be an issue.  Remember the KISS principle.  Try to create a very simple test environment, and be sure to confirm your assumptions. Re: which sample to start with... look at: *Synchronous Client Socket Example*.   Good luck!

Comment: Everything is ok. I have tested with single device. I retrieve the Bar Code, and I write to the device the price.Thanks.

Comment: Yes, of course. I apologize. I'm a little bit anxious now.

Comment: Just remember, there is no magic to this... you just have to keep working at it piece-by-piece.